# Animate collision of two balls

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation

I'm trying to make an animation with some input data. The known data includes x,y positions and radius of balls. The program works if **animation.FuncAnimation** is not called. Once the function is called, error message **"ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."** appears. Does the problem come from the way I assign the array? Please tell me how to fix it!

Here is my cod:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import matplotlib.animation as animation
# Data collection from text files
Filepath = '/Users/zhengzhiying/Desktop/DEM(CLion)/freefalling_1/'
os.chdir(Filepath)
Flowname = 'Flow'
CLname = 'CL'
Filenumber = len(os.listdir())
# Data_Number = math.ceil(0.5*(Filenumber-1))
Data_Number = 3
ID = [[] for i in range(Data_Number)]
Type = [[] for i in range(Data_Number)]
Phase = [[] for i in range(Data_Number)]
Radius = [[] for i in range(Data_Number)]
PosX = [[] for i in range(Data_Number)]
PosY = [[] for i in range(Data_Number)]
VelX = [[] for i in range(Data_Number)]
VelY = [[] for i in range(Data_Number)]
Vel_Rot = [[] for i in range(Data_Number)]
for file in range(Data_Number):
    Flow_path = f"{Filepath}{Flowname}{file}{'.txt'}"
    FD = open(Flow_path, 'r')
    non_emptyline = FD.read().splitlines()
    for index, line in enumerate(non_emptyline):
        s = line.split(' ')
        ID[file].append([])
        Type[file].append([])
        Phase[file].append([])
        Radius[file].append([])
        PosX[file].append([])
        PosY[file].append([])
        VelX[file].append([])
        VelY[file].append([])
        Vel_Rot[file].append([])
        ID[file][index] = (int)(s[0])
        Type[file][index] = (int)(s[1])
        Phase[file][index] = (int)(s[2])
        Radius[file][index] = (float)(s[3])
        PosX[file][index] = (float)(s[4])
        PosY[file][index] = (float)(s[5])
        VelX[file][index] = (float)(s[6])
        VelY[file][index] = (float)(s[7])
        Vel_Rot[file][index] = (float)(s[8])
ID = np.asfarray(ID)
Type = np.asfarray(Type)
Phase = np.asfarray(Phase)
Radius = np.asfarray(Radius).T
PosX = np.asfarray(PosX)
PosY = np.asfarray(PosY)
VelX = np.asfarray(VelX)
VelY = np.asfarray(VelY)
Vel_Rot = np.asfarray(Vel_Rot)
# create figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6), dpi=100)
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(+1.0, +3.0), ylim=(-1.0, +2.0))
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.tick_params(top=True, right=True, labeltop=True, labelright=True)

# #method1
xy_list = [PosX, PosY]
patch_list = [Circle(xy=(xy[0]), radius=r, color='b', linewidth=1.0, animated=True)
              for xy, r in zip(xy_list, Radius)]
h_text = ax.text(0.9, 0.9, 'Time: {}'.format(0), ha='center',
                 va='center', transform=ax.transAxes)

def init():
    for p in patch_list:
        ax.add_patch(p)
    return patch_list+[h_text]


def pos_update(files):
    h_text.set_text('Time: {}'.format(files/1e7))
    for p, xy in zip(patch_list, xy_list):
        p.set_center(xy[files])
    return patch_list+[h_text]


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, pos_update, init_func=init,
                               frames=Data_Number, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Dd you try some print statements for what `xy[files]` returns?  I think you have formed `xy_list` incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, but nothing came out. It seem stuck on `ax.add_patch(p)`. The form of `xy_list` is `[array([[x1,x2],...,]]), [array([[y1,y2],...,]])]`. Is this the correct form and how can I fix it?